# issue in opening android studio app in pc. The finish icon is not showing hence I cannot complete the license agreement and cannot create new project

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyN3H.jpg)

look that the finish icon is not showing , what shall I do help me out in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are just accepting the `android-sdk license` not the other two marked with red asterisk. Accept all three and then proceed.